# Gmaps.NET Dynamic markers

Tags: c#, gmap.net

I have multiple markers on a GMAP.NET map that are updated via a delegate on a thread - how can I ensure that when a new coordinate is passed from the thread to the update delegate that the marker simply updates is location, not creating a new marker?

Code is below

```
double lat = Convert.ToDouble(latlong[0]); //latitude string part of array
double longitude = Convert.ToDouble(latlong[1]); //longitude string part of array

GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("markers");
GMarkerGoogle marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, longitude),  
              GMarkerGoogleType.green);

gmap2.Overlays.Clear();
markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);

gmap2.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);

gmap2.Refresh();
```

---

The latitude and longitude are being supplied from the thread.

Cheers!

Comment: It looks like that in the code you are creating a new marker. Why are you talking about the update in your question?

Comment: I've a GPS unit that sends it's coordinates every second and what to show the updated movement via a marker on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with data from GPS units, you get some kind of device ID. Use this data to distinguish between different markers by using the `Tag` of `GMapMarker`:

```
private void AddOrUpdateMarker(string tag, double lat, double lng)
{
     // assuming "markersOverlay" is a field
     var marker = markersOverlay.Markers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Tag == tag);

     if (marker == null)
     {
          marker = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(lat, lng), GMarkerGoogleType.green);
          marker.Tag = tag;
          markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
     }

     // update the position
     marker.Position = new PointLatLng(lat, lng);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
GMapOverlay markersOverlay = new GMapOverlay("marker");
        GMapOverlay mark = new GMapOverlay("addmark");
        GMapMarker addmark = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(33.6491, 73.0833), GMarkerGoogleType.lightblue);
        GMapMarker addmark1 = new GMarkerGoogle(new PointLatLng(33.6844, 73.0479), GMarkerGoogleType.lightblue);
        mark.Markers.Add(addmark);

GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapMarker marker =
new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle(
    new GMap.NET.PointLatLng(33.626057, 73.071442),
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogleType.lightblue);
       markersOverlay.Markers.Add(addmark1);
       markersOverlay.Markers.Add(marker);
       gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(mark);

      // gMapControl1.Overlays.Clear();
        gMapControl1.MarkersEnabled = true;
        gMapControl1.Overlays.Add(markersOverlay);
        gMapControl1.Refresh();
       // gMapControl1.

        gMapControl1.Position = new PointLatLng(33.626057, 73.071442);
```

Comment: Also consider explaining what you think was wrong, and why this code fixes it.